# Javascript coding quiz not adding up

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm trying to do a simple quiz where it should sum the correct answers and incorrect answers. The thing is although I put two out of three correct answers, I keep getting the same result for the correct and incorrect array: 0. So there must be something wrong at the end, in the evaluate function. Thanks in advance

```js
var responsesArray= [];
var correct=[];
var incorrect= [];




function question2() {

  var firstQuestion = prompt('Does null === 0 ? (Yes or No)')

// why do you need to convert the answer to lowercase?
  if (firstQuestion.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
    firstQuestion = true
  } else if (firstQuestion.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
    firstQuestion = false
  } else {
// what if the user writes something other than yes or no? 
// they will have to answer the question again
    alert("Please answer either Yes or No");
    return question2();
  }
  responsesArray.push(firstQuestion); // add the true or false value to the responses array
}

question2();



function question3() {
  var js = prompt('What was the original name for JavaScript: Java, LiveScript, JavaLive, or ScriptyScript?');
  js = js.toLowerCase();
  switch (js) {
    // your own answers
    
    case "livescript":
    console.log("Correct!");
    break;
    case "Java":
    console.log("wrong");
    break;
    case "JavaLive":
    console.log("wrong");
    break;
    case "ScriptyScript":
    console.log("wrong");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Sorry the answer is LiveScript");
  }
  responsesArray.push(js);
  
  var mine = prompt('What coding language is exclusively related to the back-end: Ruby, JavaScript, HTML?');
  mine= mine.toLowerCase();
  switch (mine) {
    // your own answers
   case "ruby":
    console.log("Yeah!");
    break;
    case "html":
    console.log("ouuu I'm sorry for you");
    break;
    case "javascript":
    console.log("Yeah but so so");
    break;
  }
  responsesArray.push(mine);
}

question3();

function evaluate(responsesArray) 
{

for (var i = 0; i < responsesArray.length; i++) 
 {
  if (responsesArray[i] === true|| "livescript" || "ruby") 
    {
      correct++;

    } else{
      if (responsesArray[i] !== true|| "livescript" || "ruby") {
      incorrect++;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors. Run it and see.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, there were no other syntax errors than one missing closing brace....

Comment: @trincot Well, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array to store the correct answer and then compare correct and user response and easily can identify whether it is correct or not.

Please check below snippet.

```js
var responsesArray= [];
var correct=0;
var incorrect= 0;
//Correct answer key initialize
var index = 0;
//Initialize array to store correct answer.
var correctAnswers = [];


function question2() {
  //Save correct answer.
  correctAnswers[index++] = "yes";
  var firstQuestion = prompt('Does null === 0 ? (Yes or No)')

  // why do you need to convert the answer to lowercase?
  if (firstQuestion.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
    console.log("correct");
    firstQuestion = 'yes'
  } else if (firstQuestion.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
    console.log("in-correct");
    firstQuestion = 'no'
  } else {
    // what if the user writes something other than yes or no? 
    // they will have to answer the question again
    alert("Please answer either Yes or No");
    return question2();
  }
  responsesArray.push(firstQuestion); // add the true or false value to the responses array
}

question2();



function question3() {
  //Save correct answer.
  correctAnswers[index++] = "livescript";
  var js = prompt('What was the original name for JavaScript: Java, LiveScript, JavaLive, or ScriptyScript?');
  js = js.toLowerCase();
  switch (js) {      
      // your own answers

    case "livescript":
      console.log("Correct!");
      break;
    case "Java":
      console.log("wrong");
      break;
    case "JavaLive":
      console.log("wrong");
      break;
    case "ScriptyScript":
      console.log("wrong");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Sorry the answer is LiveScript");
  }
  responsesArray.push(js);
  
  //Save correct answer.
  correctAnswers[index++] = "ruby";
  var mine = prompt('What coding language is exclusively related to the back-end: Ruby, JavaScript, HTML?');
  mine= mine.toLowerCase();
  switch (mine) {
      // your own answers
    case "ruby":
      console.log("Yeah!");
      break;
    case "html":
      console.log("ouuu I'm sorry for you");
      break;
    case "javascript":
      console.log("Yeah but so so");
      break;
  }
  responsesArray.push(mine);
  //Call function to evaluate correct or incorrect answer
  evaluate(responsesArray,correctAnswers)
}

question3();

function evaluate(responsesArray,correctAnswers) 
{
  for (var i = 0; i < responsesArray.length; i++) 
  {
    //Match response with correct answer.
    if (responsesArray[i] === correctAnswers[i]) 
    {
      correct++;

    } else{
      if (responsesArray[i] !== correctAnswers[i]) {
        incorrect++;
      }
    }
  }
  alert("Correct : "+correct+" and Incorrect : "+incorrect);
}
```

Comment: Can you please update snippet in working mode in your question. So I can able to debug in it and can help you.

Comment: I see you have reused the `correctAnswers` variable I had already proposed in my answer. Good for you ;-)

Comment: @trincot yeah I have created a snippet using that idea. Thanks man

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Patel

Answer (score 0):

The way you test for correct answers is wrong. Instead define an array with the correct answers and verify them as follows:

```
var correct = incorrect = 0; // better initialise your variables 

function evaluate(responsesArray) {
  var correctAnswers = [true,"livescript","ruby"];
  for (var i = 0; i < responsesArray.length; i++) {
    if (responsesArray[i] === correctAnswers[i]) {
      correct++;
    } else {
      incorrect++;
    }
  }
}
```

What you had was:

```
if (responsesArray[i] === true|| "livescript" || "ruby"){
```

But this means:

```
if the answer was true, or .... "livescript" is true, or ... "ruby" is true, then
```

As JavaScript considers strings to be *truthy*, the `if` condition would always be true.

Note also that there is no need to do a second `if`, since the `else` part is only executed if the first `if` condition was false, which means you already have filtered for the cases where the answer was wrong.

Finally, your counter variables should be defined before you start incrementing them. It works without this definition, but if one of the two variables is not incremented, it will still be undefined after your call to `evaluate`. Better always define your variables.

Comment: no, your solution simply store the correct answers that you give them already in the correctAnswers variable inside the correct variable.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I just translated your wrong `if` code to a right syntax, putting the correct values not in the `if` but in a variable. But I see you preferred the answer from Rahul, who copied my idea in fact. But no problem ;-)

Comment: Yes you're right, however Rahul added the other 50% to make it work (index++, call function, two arguments in the evaluate function...) Thanks to both of you ;)